# why does microsoft office ignore owner file?

Tags: file-sharing, microsoft-office

We started rolling out Seafile as replacement for our old file-server.

Everything works fine except some users who work on excel files together have problems with concurrent editing. Normally if one user tries to open a file that another user already opened office warns the second user and opens the file in read-only mode.

As I understood this is implemented by creation of a special $~filename file which (as stated by Microsoft in this article: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211632 under "Owner File") holds information about the user that is currently working on the file. Seafile can be configured to sync these files, and is on these machines. I can also see the file being synced and appearing on the other clients.

Nonetheless Office is not complaining when I try to open the file on the second client.
Can you tell me what the problem might be?

Comment: Have you checked the `owner file` with a text editor (such as `notepad++`)? It usually contains a reference to a `.lock file`. Which contains more information about the lock. If the `.lock file` can't be found, Office won't complain about the lock, and create a second `owner file` (and the first one will get cleaned up on reboot)

Comment: As you can see in this screenshot of a hex editor opening the file: http://pbrd.co/1x3RFiB there is no reference to such a lock file.

Comment: I am using office 2013 on both clients and if I try to open the file twice on one client (with different users) it shows that warning.